# What are the semi-norms on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $\| AB\| = \| BA\|$, for all $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

What are the semi-norms on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $\| AB\| = \| BA\|$, for all $A$ and $B$ in $M_n(\mathbb C)$, $n ≥ 2$?

I came across this exercise (an oral exercise), and I have thought about this : [Is there a semi-norm that respects matrix similitary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670577/is-there-a-semi-norm-that-respects-matrix-similitary)

Do you have another idea to solve this problem? It does not seem really natural to directly think of similitary and does not allow to conclude apparently: are these the only such semi-norms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $\|E_{ij}\|=0$ whenever $i\ne j$ because
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}
\text{ and } \pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}=0.
$$
It follows that $\|F\|=0$ for any matrix $F$ with a zero diagonal.

Secondly, $\|E_{ii}-E_{i+1,\,i+1}\|=0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ because
\begin{align}
\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}\right\|
&=\left\|\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\right\|\\
&=\left\|\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}\right\|\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\right\|\\
&=0\text{ (because the matrix has a zero diagonal)}.
\end{align}
It follows that $\|T\|=0$ whenever $T$ is a traceless diagonal matrix, because $T$ is a linear combination of $E_{ii}-E_{i+1,\,i+1},\ i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. (We have actually used similarity in the above, namely, every traceless matrix is similar to a zero-diagonal matrix, but such use at least is not explicit.)

Now, for any matrix $A$, let $c=\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A)}{n}$. Then $A$ can be split into a sum of the form $cI+T+F$, where $F$ is the off-diagonal part of $A$ and $T$ is a traceless diagonal matrix. Hence
$$
\|A\|=\|cI+T+F\|\le\|cI\|+\|T\|+\|F\|=\|cI\|
$$
and
$$
\|cI\|=\|A-T-F\|\le\|A\|+\|T\|+\|F\|=\|A\|,
$$
meaning that $\|A\|=\|cI\|=\left|\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A)}{n}\right|\|I\|$. In other words, $\|\cdot\|$ must be a scalar multiple of the absolute matrix trace.

Comment: Excellent. This is really your domain  : ) Thank you.

Comment: "every traceless matrix is similar to a zero-diagonal matrix, but such use at least is not explicit": Indeed, and it is quite a classical result.